# .htaccess simple redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect old internal page to my home page. My .htacess file starts like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Redirect 301 /int/index.php?m=help https://website.com
```

Further down I have more rules to force SSL and no "www" and these rules are working fine, but for some reason `Redirect` directive is being ignored, client can open the page without being redirected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's due to the `?m=help`. I would use a `RewriteRule` like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m=help
RewriteRule index\.php https://website.com? [R=301,L]
```

Please note:

1. the ? at the end of the rewritten path is needed to cut off the `?m=help`; if you omit it, you'll redirect to `https://website.com?m=help`
2. the `[R=301,L]` means: "redirect to the page" and (L) "stop the rewrite engine after applying this rule", that is, no additional rewriting will be appied to the string `https://website.com?`

Comment: Great answer! And thank you for additional notes.